# animate inline element scroll full width

Tags: css, css-animations

for the following paragraph, I want to animate to scroll `span` element upon mouse hover. It will scroll to the right until the end.

```
  <div class="one_line">
    <span>
        NoMagic framework doesn't try to put anything into the blackbox. We hope you read the core source code and try to get fully understanding before you start to using it. And we hope you forking our project and creating your own database helper function sets based on your need.

        Using NoMagic, you will turn the MySQL database into a schemaless solution, the schemaless database will save your time so that you don't need to spend to much time in planning database table structure.
    </span>
  </div>
```

the css I already have

```
.one_line {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    &:hover {
      animation-name: scroll;
      animation-duration: 6s;
    } 
  }
}

@keyframes scroll {
  50% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome, firefox, ie10

Comment: Have tried prefixing @keyframes, animation-name, animation-duration with browser specific declaration (say -moz-, -webkit- etc.,)?

Comment: no, not yet. But it can animate without -moz prefix in firefox. I guess the problem is not about the syntax.

Comment: can you explain "@keyframes sroll" block little more in detail for me please?

Comment: it's used to scroll content of `div.one_line` to the right. Because, the content is more wider than the container, so I will it to be able to scroll automatically when mouse over.

Answer (score 1):

Up to my knowledge using CSS animate we can only animate the entire tag itself but not the content in it (i.e.) in this case we can move the entire span across the page dimension but not the text inside it. So i made it using transform property which is more flexible.

I have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/THEyG/6/) to demonstrate this.

CSS Animate code that i had changed:

```
@keyframes scroll { 
   0%   {  
         transform:translateX(0);  
        }  
   100% {  
         transform:translateX(-100%);  
        }
}
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: your jsFiddle is not working, and what I want is actually the moving one liner, which can show the full length text

Comment: Check with firefox browser, for other browsers you have to write browser specific declarations. To show full length text increase the span width and animation-duration accordingly so as to completely cover the full text.

Comment: manually change the length is not a solution to my question. If there are many rows with different length, I can't set one length which fit all. If javascript can do it, I will also accept it as an answer.But how can javascript get the true width of the span?

Comment: I had came up with an CSS solutions(used transform in keyframes), you can see it on http://jsfiddle.net/THEyG/6/ , is this okay?